# Handling windows Security when accesing webpage

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

Im trying to make login into a page for making the testing on it. The problem is when opening the page "Windows Scurity" appears and the page does not load till you fill it. Also tried to put the credentials on the link.

It is possible to make some script to wait in background this window and fill it? Calling it before the driver.navigate line?

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mywebpage.com/loader.aspx");
                //NEVER REACH THIS PART WINDOWS SECURITY
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Any solution for this problem?[windows security photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5GiX.png)

Comment: That's not an alert, That's browser authentication popup. you can find many examples on  google it how to handle authentication popup in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

***You can have a look at below helper method which would wait for Pop-Up/Overlay for specific time and fills detail as soon as Overlay appears also check modal gets closed based of visibility of overlay***

```
public synchronized void anyPop-UpHandler(int timeOut, String name, String pwd) {
        try {
                wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf("Xpath of Overlay"));
                driver.findElement(By.XPath("Xpath of name input field")).sendKeys(name);
                driver.findElement(By.XPath("Xpath of pwd input field")).sendKeys(pwd);
                driver.findElement(By.XPath("Xpath of ok button")).click();
                wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>((WebDriver) driver).withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
                }catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
```